# AVPlayer Pause and play issues when app goes background

Tags: iphone, ios, avplayer

It's working correctly if the app just become inactive/active (when some alert came or by double clicking on home button)

```
AVPlayer *player;

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [player pause];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [player play];
}
```

If the app goes to background (by clicking home button) and comes back, it's not playing from paused position instead of that it is playing from different point (sometimes from start, sometimes from middle).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1) Firstly add `float *time`  in `appDelegate.h` file.

2) Take `current time` in `applicationWillResignActive`

3) Add below methods

`ApplicationWillResignActive` method `pause` player and `save` `current` `time` of player

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
   [player pause];
   time = player.currentTime
}
```

Now in `applicationDidBecomeActive` add `seekToTime`

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  [player seekToTime:time toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
  [player play];
}
```

Comment: Earlier i was doing the same seekToTime didn't work for me, apple is doing some optimization while seeking. Instead of that we have to use             [_videoPlayer seekToTime:_pausedTime toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero]; to work correctly

Answer (score 1):

You should call the this methods before application is going to background.
[player pause];
or
[player stop];